# How to set maximum heap size (-Xmx) for Java application that gets started via "gradle run"?

Tags: java, gradle, parameters, heap-memory

If we want to clean, build and then run our application, we use `./gradlew clean run`.
`run` is part of [the Gradle Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

What we want to achieve is to assign a certain maximum heap size to the application using `run`, something similar to `./gradlew clean run -Xmx1G`.
The result should equal running `java -Xmx16G -jar /path/to/my/app.jar`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

*Edit: Just to make sure, I do not want to increase the build deamons's max heap but the max heap of the application that gets started by gradle.*

Comment: Try **applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xmx1G"]**

Comment: you could set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS on the environment (export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx1G"), every jvm that is started by any subprocess will pick up that string and treat it as if it was specified directly in the commandline

Comment: @BenoArakelyan: Thanks, that works! Do you also know a solution where I can pass such `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` on the command line like `./gradlew clean run applicationDefaultJvmArgs=["-Xmx1G"]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As reported in the [Installing Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) for version 4.2.1:

> Note that it’s not currently possible to set JVM options for Gradle on
>   the command line.

What you are looking for can be achieved modifying the `build.gradle` script. You can do it adding this little code snippet to your `build.gradle` file:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xmx16g']
}
```

If you want to configure also the initial Java heap size, add the following code:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xms1g', '-Xmx16g']
}
```